# Update Data in SqlDatabase Using CommonTable Expression

Tags: sql

how to update these table

```
With Cte as (Select A.C_Value[Val1], B.C_value[Val2]
             From Candidates As A
             Inner Join Candidates As B on A.C_code=B.C_code and B.C_srl=22
             where A.C_srl=18 and A.C_code=1005)
Update Cte Set val1 = 22, Val2 = 36
```

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Pick better names for aliases than "a" and "b". Also explain why you join a table to itself and then want to update. Either the relationship is 1:1 so the update is unnecessary because the target column is already the value of the source column, or the relationship is not 1:1 in which case you have multiple rows of the left/right matching multiple rows on the right/left and you cannot set a single cell to have multiple values. (Other words it's a nonsense to self join a table and then update it; just update the table without doing the join)

Comment: And which row do you want to update, a or by?

Comment: I am joining same table muti0le time cause of value is in it with same name. Its in as tabular structure  like ..C_code,c_value . C_code repeated all time till end of 150 rows but value are differ so that a cause i am joining table